# Why do the buttons on my Incredible occasionally light up?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, buttons

I've noticed that sometimes the four buttons at the bottom of my HTC Incredible sometimes light up for a couple seconds at a time, even when the phone is just sitting unused on my desk.  Until now I've attributed this to a software bug, but I recently noticed it doing this while I was digging around in my email on my computer.

Does this indicate data transfer?  Or does it have some other significance?

Comment: Your phone is becoming sentient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You phone should light up when you activate it.

When an internal process either stops or wakes up you phone (like you said to start data transfer) or on other actions the lights can light up.

When a process crashes my phone lights up the control keys too, usually with a buzz.

Answer (score 1):

My Incredible does this as well.  I have been told that this also is sometimes used by applications to indicate that an app has downloaded updated data.  For instance, if the HTC mail application has downloaded new emails.  But I haven't taken the time to see if this is accurate or not.